# Cannot open database "Inventory_New" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backgroundworker

I have made my database in **SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition** and the software is made in **VS C# Windows Form** and is used to store data of inventory of a big company.

I use a **BackgroundWorker** in the software to continuously check if the stock has been updated or not but for some reason it shows the below error.

> Cannot open database "Inventory_New" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'sa'.

I have already gone through many blogs and article but none of the solution works for me.

I can login with Sql Server Management Studio with the user **sa** and it is responding well.

The software works just fine but throughout the day it randomly shows the above error (6-7 time a day no fixed time)

### SQL Error Log

Below is the error i found in SQL Error Log but i do not understand what that means

> 2017-05-12 05:01:41.78 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State:
>   38.
>  2017-05-12 05:01:41.78 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT:
>   ]

### Edit

Lately i saw that when i got this error the **database for some reason went in recovery mode**. 
I also checked some articles for why the Database goes in recovery mode but none of them seems to fit the bill because in my case the database comes online automatically after 2-3 seconds of short break.

Comment: Can you login with Sql Server Management Studio with the user sa?

Comment: @Max i have already gone through many blogs and article but none of the solution works for me

Comment: @user2657943 yes i can and it is responding well but throughout the day it randomly pops this error message

Comment: Update the question and better specify the circumstance of the error. Always ? Random ? After x time ? Otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: @Max sir, what kind of details you want me to share?

Comment: Express, developer, standard or enterprise version of SQL?  you should have SQL logs to go with this to also maybe expand on the error

Comment: @BugFinder the software works just fine but throughout the day it randomly shows the above error (6-7 time a day no fixed time)

Comment: So you missed the entire point ............

Comment: OK, I seem to remember that there are more limitations than the 1gb memory when it comes to practical use. so the login isnt failing, its just not able to open the database.  You may have OS limitations to handle too

Comment: A bigger question is: why are you using the 'sa' user!!

Comment: Also "I use a BackgroundWorker in the software to continuously check if the stock has been updated" : consider using SqlDependency: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates you the database, Inventory_New, that can't be open. This means that your application asks for this database as the initial catalog, but the database is not online. It can be in the middle of restore, for example, or just be offline.
When you connect to server using Management Studio, you don't submit that database, I guess the default database for sa login is master,
 so you logged in successfully.
You should check why your Inventory_New database is not online

Comment: I have no clue, I am not using any alter statements in the whole program and their is no way someone can make the DB offline without alter statements.

Comment: If you are not the only sysadmin on the server, anyone else can do it, even db_owher of that database can put it offline. Did you check the state of your database when the error occured? You can also check the SQL Server error log because all the command such as ALTER DATABASE SET OFFLINE are registered there, so you can find out if the database was restoring, etc

Comment: i checked it and posted the error log above and i even saw at the time i got this error the SQL database went into recovery mode (i dont know why)

Comment: Maybe your database has the autoclose option turned on? In this case it goes offline every time there was no active connection and goes online every time it's requested. It's better to change this option to false, every time it takes server resources to bring it online

Comment: The other and the last option for being in recovery state is recent RESTORE. A database runs only two types of recovery, the start recovery(when it goes online) and after restore. And if if was restored, you can see this in errorlog too

Comment: WOW, i was just searching about this topic but i am confused about the benefits of keeping it on?

Comment: So your database has autoclose set to TRUE?

Comment: yes sir and i have read the cons of it but it also free's memory on sql connection close, right?

Comment: I can suggest tou to read this article: http://sqlmag.com/blog/worst-practice-allowing-autoclose-sql-server-databases

Comment: i just finished reading the same article but i want to ask you what if i set the "AUTOCLOSE=OFF" then will the memory used by each user be stacked up leading to a huge memory consumption on server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144518/discussion-between-agent-spock-and-sepupic).

Comment: The memory that an opened database occupies is almost nothing, there is a bit of metadata and you can measure how many database pages are in memory in any time using sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors filtering by your database_id. Every page occupies 8Kb so you can do the math and see that is really very small amount of memory

Comment: But sir I have 5 PC's connected to server at all time which fires a query in a loop at server to check for any updations going on the pc. This might create many multiple 8kb files and within an hour it will hang the pc.

Comment: I wrote you in chat but I cannot see your answers there, excuse me I've never used the cat before on this site maybe I did smth wrong. I don't understand about what files you speak

Comment: Nothing else file is created when someone uses a database, database has it's data and log file and does not produce any additional file. The memory we are talking about is RAM. Your server has a buffer pool limited by max server memory option or not limited at all, this pool is shared between data from all online databases. When you modify data the data is never modified on disk but in memory only so it's loaded into the buffer pool. The same is for select: you never reads from disk but from buffer pool. When database goes offline all memoty occupied by it's data is marked as free

Comment: So if you constantly use a database, it make no sense to free the memory every minute and re-read the data every time someone executes smth using your database data, this re-reading from disk costs much, ideally, the great part of database data is always in memory ready to be used

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking that your connections are all closed and Disposed.

Put your SqlConnection into a using block and see if that improves things:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnect))
{
...
}
```

If you aren't doing that, it's quite likely that SQL has run out of connections - particularly if you are creating, opening, and discarding a new connection.

Comment: i am dropping the connection as soon as i retrieve the data and using the same method for it.